# "sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed" OR "TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'null'"

Tags: python, sql, null, flask-sqlalchemy, nullable

I am getting a recursive error.

Here is the code I am getting an error on:

```py
class Shooter(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "shooters"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.id'),
                        nullable=False)

    @property
    def total_score(self):
        scores = map(lambda a: a.score, self.scores)
        total = reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, scores)
        return total
```

Here is the error I am getting with this code, which I will refer to as "Error 1":
`sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: shooters.team_id`

After browsing SO for an answer I learned that I could rewrite

```
team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.id'),
                        nullable=False)
```

as

```
team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.id'),
                        null=True)
```

but that would return another error, "Error 2":
`TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'null'`

I went back to SO again to look for an answer and it told me that putting `nullable=False` in place of `null=True` would fix it, but that would return Error 1...

So if fixing Error 1 leads me to Error 2 and vice versa, how can I fix this recursive error?

Thank you.

update: talked with my coding instructor and fixed Error 1

update 2: maybe fixed Error 2 because the replies on this post said that you can't replace "nullable=False" with "null=True". Thank you for your help! Hopefully, this means the problem is solved, but we'll see.

Comment: Where did you see you could replace `nullable=False` with `null=True` ? That is simply not true. Then, I cannot reproduce your `IntegrityError`. Please [edit] your question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: first error suggests that you have mistake in your database - you have some shooter without value `team_id` and you should fix it manually using external tools - database editors like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/). OR you try to create new new shooter without `team_id` - and this is wrong. But you didn't show FULL error message so we can't see what is the real problem.

Comment: based on other question it may need `nullable=False` or `nullable=True`, not `null=...`

Comment: @furas Thank you, I think you might have solved the problem with that last reply, talking with my instructor now to confirm that it works